# Implementing custom `Selector` user control using a trigger to control style of selected item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have implemented a simple implementation of `Selector` for an equivalent custom selectable `ItemsControl`

```
public class SelectableControl : Selector
{
}
```

I'm trying to set up triggers to apply style to the selected item, but of course `ContentPresenter` doesn't have the `IsSelected` property.  How can I handle this?  There must be another class that I have to use, but I cannot find information about this.

```
<local:SelectableControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="true" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</local:SelectableControl.Resources>
```

Full usage for better reference:

```
<local:SelectableControl ItemsSource="{Binding Blobs}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}">
    <local:SelectableControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="true" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </local:SelectableControl.Resources>
    <local:SelectableControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="White">
                <Ellipse 
                    Width="19.0" 
                    Height="19.0" 
                    Fill="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </local:SelectableControl.ItemTemplate>
    <local:SelectableControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BlobToGridColumnConverter}}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="3" />
        </Style>
    </local:SelectableControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <local:SelectableControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid 
                IsItemsHost="True"
                helperLogic:GridHelpers.RowCount="4"
                helperLogic:GridHelpers.StarRows="0,1,3"
                helperLogic:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding Path=Blobs, Converter={StaticResource BlobsToNumberColumnsConverter}}"
                >
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </local:SelectableControl.ItemsPanel>
</local:SelectableControl>
```

Comment: Why won't you subclass a ListBox?

Comment: @Clemens the control will not look anything like a list or have text, so I was not thinking it would be a likely candidate

Comment: @Clemens I tried switching over to ListBox and seem to have issues with content being set more than once.  Usually that's an easy error to fix, but can't figure out why it's triggered, so may not be the right piece.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this derived ListBox](https://github.com/ClemensFischer/XAML-Map-Control/blob/master/MapControl/Shared/MapItemsControl.cs) which displays items on a map at geographic locations. It does not at all look like a list.

Comment: @Clemens  Thank you.  I ended up achieving what I needed with a pure ListBox and overlaying a Grid with the above code.  I think the `ItemsPanelTemplate` has to be set with a style for some reason.